# Org-mode: footnotes with dollar sign

Tags: org-mode

I've run into a very strange issue with Org-mode 8.2.10 footnotes. Given the following text, where `|` represents point and `[empty-line]` represents an empty line,

> [empty-line]
>
> Foo bar baz =$= | foo bar baz
>
> [empty-line]

It is not possible to insert a footnote at point, any position on the line after point, or on the immediately following line. `Cannot insert a footnote here` is displayed when typing`C-c C-x f`.

If the `=`'s are removed, inserting footnotes works fine.

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `$` being a [LaTeX operator](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html)?

Comment: Indeed.  As a workaround, you can add a space between `$` and `=`, insert the footnote, then remove the space.

Comment: I edited your post based on what I think you're doing, feel free to revert if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work in Org Mode 8.3.4 without any problems.

Comment: Alright then, I'll guess I'll eventually upgrade...eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is discussed in this [message](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-10/msg00549.html) from 2011:

> For what it's worth, this not directly related to footnotes.  It's
>   a weakness in `org-inside-LaTeX-fragment-p', which returns a non-nil
>   value after =\begin{document}= instead of nil.  And, obviously, one
>   cannot add a footnote inside a LaTeX fragment...

I didn't find any mention of this problem in the commit logs but I suspect this has been fixed by commit [176681bc65b5c787dc0737ccd523afd19b7ea4c0](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=176681bc65b5c787dc0737ccd523afd19b7ea4c0) (2015-02-15) where the call to `org-footnote-in-valid-context-p` has been replaced by one to the new function `org-footnote--allow-reference-p`.

As a workaround before upgrading, you can temporarily add a space between $ and =, insert the footnote, then remove the space.